# ThreadPoolExecutor set queue timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, timeout, threadpoolexecutor

I want to remove items that are in the queue longer than a certain time.

One approach that came to my mind is to wrap BlockingQueue, override take method with adding a timestamp and start a daemon thread which will check whether the time is out and remove items from the queue.

Are there any better solutions to set a timeout for a queue in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: So you're looking for some sort of reverse `DelayQueue`.

Comment: Would `ThreadPoolExecutor.setKeepAliveTime()` or `setMaximumPoolSize()` help?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, smth like this

Comment: @MalteHartwig unfortunately this two options is for exceeding threads, but not the queue

Comment: I see. So if an item is either processing or waiting for too long you want it interrupted and removed?

Comment: @MalteHartwig I want to remove an item from the waiting queue. When processing started - item is not in the queue anymore, so there is no problem with interruption.

Comment: Is there some reason why the item has to be dropped immediately? You could wrap a BlockingQueue so that all items get a timestamp when added. On removal, you just loop until you find an item that has not expired. Would that work for you?

Comment: @UliSchlachter that could be one of the possible solutions too, but I want to know is there any way to prevent wrapping and use some OOTB staff.

Comment: Is the delay constant? If the head of the queue is always the closest to timeout you could run a task to offer your jobs to workers synchronously, with the offer timeout set to the queue timeout.